# A question about the Littlewood-Paley decomposition.

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $\{f_k(x)\}_{k=0}^\infty$ be a Littlewood-Paley decompositon, that is, 
$$ f_k \in C_c^\infty $$ 
$$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty f_k (x) = 1,$$
$$ \text{supp} f_0 \subset \{ |x| \leq 2 \},$$
$$ \exists f \in C_c^\infty   \; \text{such that}\; \text{supp} f \subset \{ 2^{-1} \leq |x| \leq 2 \} \; \text{satisfying}\; f_k (x) = f(x/2^k).$$
Then I hope to show that there exist $C, C'>0$ such that $$ C' \sum_{k=0}^\infty \| f_k(g) \|_{L^2}^2 \le \| g \|_{L^2}^2 \le C \sum_{k=0}^\infty \| f_k(g) \|_{L^2}^2$$ for $g \in L^2 (\mathbb R)$. Here $C_c^\infty$ means $C^\infty$ functions with compact support and $\text{supp}$ means the support.